# save MySQL Packet Size after shutdown

Tags: mysql, apache

Hi there
I have problem with my mysql server.
I have windows 7, apche 2.2,php5.2 and mysql 5.0.51b-community-nt on my laptop(localhost)
I ran this query in mysql command line :

```
set global max_allowed_packet=16*1024*1024;
```

but after restart max_allowed_packet is 1MB(default).

What should I do to save changes, and keep them after shutdown?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

add

```
max_allowed_packet=16M
```

to your `my.ini`

Answer (score 1):

The setting is in your settings-file that gets read when starting. Change the setting there so it is kept like that.

I can't find the default location for my.ini (or my.conf) files quickly, but it shouldn't be hard to find.

Answer (score 1):

You need to save the configuration in the config file `my.ini` on Windows or `my.cnf` on Linux.

Answer (score 0):

You should set that in the MySQL option file, usually my.cnf, or my.ini in your (Windows) case.

Check the mysql documents: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/option-files.html